# Install method not being called in c# install project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, windows-installer, msdn

I am working through an [msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49b92ztk%28v=VS.90%29.aspx#Y1200) in VS08 on how to create a custom installer and I have followed it to the letter. The only change I made was that I implemented the code in C# instead of VB. It compiles without any errors and appears to install, but the overridden install method is not being called and therefore, nothing is being "installed."

From what I have read online while researching this problem, I have discovered that some people have had problems getting their uninstall method to be called, but their install method works fine. I decided to follow through on some of those suggestions thinking it might inadvertently help me, so my code is a little more flushed out than the msdn example, but none of the overridden functions at the bottom of my code are being called.

I have paid close attention to detail, but because of the seeming absence of documentation on this problem, I feel like I must be missing something simple. My code for the class library is below.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration.Install;


namespace DBCustomAction
{
   public partial class CsDeployInstaller : Installer
   {
      public CsDeployInstaller()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private string GetSql(string Name)
      {
         try
         {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Stream strm = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(asm.GetName().Name + "." + Name);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(strm, System.Text.Encoding.Default);
            // System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;                  
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            Console.Write("In GetSql:" + ex.Message);
            throw ex;
         }
      }

      private void ExecuteSql(string DataBaseName, string Sql)
      {
         string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["masterConnectionString"].ToString();             
         //string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
         SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
         System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand Command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(Sql, sqlConnection1);
         Command.Connection.Open();
         Command.Connection.ChangeDatabase(DataBaseName);

         try
         {
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         finally
         {
            Command.Connection.Close();
         }
      }

      protected void AddDBTable(string strDBName)
      {
         try
         {
            ExecuteSql("master", "CREATE DATABASE " + strDBName);
            ExecuteSql(strDBName, GetSql("sql.txt"));
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("In exception handler:" + ex.Message);
         }
      }

      public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Install is working");
         base.Install(stateSaver);

         AddDBTable(this.Context.Parameters["dbname"]);
      }

      public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("I am uninstalling this");
         base.Uninstall(savedState);
      }

      public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Commit Function");
         base.Commit(savedState);
      }

      public override void Rollback(IDictionary savedState)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("rollback works!");
         base.Rollback(savedState);
      }
   }
}
```

None of the Console.WriteLine commands ever get called. Just for fun, I also ran a trace to detect if the database was even being acknowledged by the installer and there was nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how else to answer your question other than that this one works:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cdb5eda(v=VS.100).aspx

If you follow those steps you should be good.

Comment: Thanks.. it worked! Not sure what I was doing wrong.. but this link is way more helpful.